# How to fix JavaScript heap out of memory error when importing data to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Anyone who can point me in right direction why I cant import the data to mongodb? When I try to import only the first 100 lines of the total file I get

> database-operations git:(master) ✗ node import_acparts_to_mongdb.js
>   (node:10216) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11
>   close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increas e
>   limit ➜  database-operations git:(master) ✗

I try to import 600.000 lines from the same file, a csv file that has following structure:

facility;item_number;part_name;part_description;net_weight;customs_statistical
PBL;5535210444;COVER;COVER;0;84314980
D37;5535211545;BRACKET;BRACKET-FIRE SUPP TANK A101-20;2,939;72169110
PBL;5535211234;BRACKET;BRACKET-FIRE SUPP TANK A101-20;2,939;84314300
PBL;5535212478;RING-SNAP;RING-SNAP;0,045;84314980
.......
.......

> ➜  database-operations git:(master) ✗ node import_acparts_to_mongdb.js
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> 38787 ms: Mark-sweep 1384.9 (1436.8) -> 1384.8 (1436.8) MB, 1181.9
>   / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].    39964
>   ms: Mark-sweep 1384.8 (1436.8) -> 1384.8 (1436.8) MB, 1177.7 / 0.0 ms
>   [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].    41199 ms:
>   Mark-sweep 1384.8 (1436.8) -> 1385.8 (1420.8) MB, 1234.0 / 0.0 ms
>   [last resort gc].    42429 ms: Mark-sweep 1385.8 (1420.8) -> 1386.9
>   (1420.8) MB, 1229.8 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0x4962c9cfb39 
>       1: $__validate [/Users/isaklafleur/Dropbox/Isak/Coding/Other/autoMDM/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:~1404]
>   [pc=0xe52ebc4f d97] (this=0x383867c1f221 ,callback=0x383867c201e1 )
>       2: validate [/Users/isaklafleur/Dropbox/Isak/Coding/Other/autoMDM/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:~1324]
>   [pc=0x...
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory  1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]  2:
>   node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local,
>   v8::Local) [/usr/local/bin/node]  3:
>   v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int,
>   bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/bin/node]  5:
>   v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int,
>   v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node] 
>   6: 0xe52eb8079a7 [1]    10085 abort      node
>   import_acparts_to_mongdb.js ➜  database-operations git:(master) ✗

---

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
    parse       = require('csv-parse'),
    path        = require('path'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    ACpart      = require('./models/acparts');

mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/automdm_test');

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
    // we're connected!

    const p = path.join(__dirname, '/../', 'file-operations', 'csv-files');
    //console.log(p);

    const parser = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function(err, data){
        //console.log(data);
        const facility = data.map((item,i) => data[i][0]);
        const item_number = data.map((item,i) => data[i][1]);
        const part_name = data.map((item,i) => data[i][2]);
        const part_description = data.map((item,i) => data[i][3]);
        const net_weight = data.map((item,i) => data[i][4]);
        const customs_statistical = data.map((item,i) => data[i][5]);

        // Looping and storing the data into mongodb
        for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

            const newACpart = new ACpart();
            newACpart.facility = facility[i]
            newACpart.item_number = item_number[i];
            newACpart.part_name = part_name[i];
            newACpart.part_description = part_description[i];
            newACpart.net_weight = net_weight[i];
            newACpart.customs_statistical = customs_statistical[i];
            newACpart.save()
            .then(function() {
                mongoose.disconnect();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('There was an error', err);
            });
        }
    });
    fs.createReadStream(p + '/mrsparts.csv').pipe(parser);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to put everything in memory if it's larger than you heap. Use a streaming CSV parser, like one of those:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-stream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-stream-csv
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-csv-enhanced
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv

And then send it to the database in batches instead of all at once.

Comment: thank you for your answer. As you can see I'm using the csv-parser. Can you point me in right direction on how to divide it and send it in batches? :)